# How to get uri from apollo client object

Tags: apollo-client

Context: I'm working with micro front-end, and I want to access the uri of the apollo client. I'm currently passing the whole client object and I don't want to pass also the uri each time.
I defined my ApolloClient object like this:

```js
new ApolloClient({
    ...
    link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, new HttpLink({ uri: process.env.BACKEND_URL })]),
  });
```

How can I access the uri from the client object ?

```js
const client = useApolloClient();
const uri = client.???
```

Answer (score -3):

the uri is a field on the object, so you should be able use the [Dot property accessor: object.property](https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/) to obtain the URI.  You can learn more about the [HTTP Link constructor in the Apollo Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-http/)